# .net core tests in console project

Tags: .net-core, xunit

I like to put my tests with my code [and *why* is not the point of this question] - I create a .net core console application - add xunit, xunit test runner, but I can't get dotnet or the resharper addin to discover any tests in the application.  It works fine if I do it in not a console app.   Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: we need to see ALL the relevant code. to help you we need to be able to reproduce the issue

Comment: Did you observe similar behaviour when you put test and production code in different projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new test project and comparing, as far as I can tell, the magic difference is:

```
<IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
```

in the csproj.   I guess without that, something is throwing away the tests?